# Django query : Call values() on user__userprofile

Tags: django, foreign-keys, group-by, annotate

I have the following models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) 
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Game(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Achievement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
```

In settings.py I have set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` to my UserProfile class.

For a given game, I want to get a list of the users who have, say, more than five achievements for that game.

So what I did was the following:

```
candidates = Achievement.objects.filter(game=game).values('user').annotate(nba=Count('id')).filter(nba__gte=5).order_by('-user__userprofile__score')
```

Now it works but the problem is that I get a list of values with the user id and his nba (number of achievements). But I need to print the score in template and also access other attributes of UserProfile...

So I tried changing ".values('user')" to:

```
.values('user','user__userprofile__score')
```

But it doesn't work! I get an error:

```
invalid field user__userprofile__score
```

Note that it works if I do:

```
.values('user','user__username')
```

Which seems to indicate that values can be called on attributes but not on foreignkey ?

I have also tried another way using "django-batch-select" application:

```
batch = Batch('achievement_set').filter(game=game)
candidates = User.objects.batch_select(achieved=batch).exclude(achieved__is_null=True)
```

But I get an error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'achieved' into field.
```

It works if I remove the "exclude" statement, but then I get a list of ALL users including those who don't have any achievement for this game (they get: achieved == [])

I've been searching everywhere but can't find a solution to my problem... some help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I was hoping to do it in one query... anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get user profiles by one extra query:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id__in=[x['user'] for x in candidates])
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you have to remove `values('user')` and add to the end of query_set `only('user', 'user__profile')` and `select_related('user', 'user__profile')`

```
candidates = [i.user for i in Achievement.objects.\
    select_related('user', 'user__userprofile').\
    annotate(nba=Count('id')).\
    filter(game=game, nba__gte=5).\
    only('user', 'user__userprofile').\
    order_by('-user__userprofile__score')]
```

I test on my project this `select_related` and `only`and it works

```
>>> db.connection.queries = []
>>> p = [(i.object, i.object.owner) for i in models.ImageOrVideo.objects.\
      select_related('object', 'object__owner').\
      only('object').all().\
      order_by('-object__owner__id')]
...
>>> len(db.connection.queries)
1
```

Comment: but if you remove values(), then the nba=Count('id') is not grouped by user so we don't get the number of achievements per user ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: I added `annotate` to query and looked at result query, and there was `GROUP BY` section.
But `only()` didn't save situation and SQL query looks huge and ugly.